# present storyboard controller from a programmed made controller

Tags: ios, swift, view, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

Hi my app is made without a storyboard and in one of my classes I want to present the one controller made in my storyboard but it crashes every time here are some screen shots
[image: The Controller im trying to [present]

[!][This is how im presenting it[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3JfB.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3JfB.png)

Comment: Please add code not a screenshot of the code. Anyways the code you are claiming is not how you present but how you create nav controller. Plus add error, it is hard to guess the problem from your information

Comment: If you think an answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: what? that doesn't even make sense

Answer (score 1):

If you want to present something that is in the storyboard, you need to instantiate the VC class using `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`:

```
let newNoteVC = UIStoryboard.main.
    instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "A")
```

`"A"` is the storyboard ID that you gave the VC.

Now it can be presented:

```
present(newNoteVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: in swift 3 its like this   let aViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "A") as! newNoteController

Comment: but it still crashes when i do it :/

Comment: @TyeHowatt On which line did it crash? What does the log say? You have to tell me these before I can answer.